# Mongoose unique values from inner documents array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have such a schema:

```
User = {
    field1: {type: String},
    field2: {type: String},
    field3: [
        {
            field4: {type: String},
            field5: {type: String},
            field6: {type: String}
        }
    ]
}
```

There are multiple users in DB and they can have same objects in the nested documents array. Objects in the array are unique for each user, but several users can have duplicates.

So, the question is: I need mongoose to return an array of [{field5: ..., field6:...}], where there are no duplicates. I mean, I need a unique array not from 1 user, I need to collect all unique field5, field6 objects across all users in the database.

Example:

```
User1 = {
    name: "Andrew",
    surname: "Pavlov"
    orgInfo: [
        {orgId: "orgId-1", INN: "inn-1", KPP: "kpp-1"},
        {orgId: "orgId-2", INN: "inn-2", KPP: "kpp-2"},
        {orgId: "orgId-3", INN: "inn-3", KPP: "kpp-3"},
    ]
}

User2 = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe"
    orgInfo: [
        {orgId: "orgId-2", INN: "inn-2", KPP: "kpp-2"},
        {orgId: "orgId-4", INN: "inn-4", KPP: "kpp-4"},
    ]
}

User3 = {
    name: "Vasya",
    surname: "Pupkin"
    orgInfo: [
        {orgId: "orgId-1", INN: "inn-1", KPP: "kpp-1"},
        {orgId: "orgId-5", INN: "inn-5", KPP: "kpp-5"},
        {orgId: "orgId-7", INN: "inn-7", KPP: "kpp-7"},
    ]
}
```

The query on this collection should return:

```
[
    {INN: "inn-1", KPP: "kpp-1"},
    {INN: "inn-2", KPP: "kpp-2"},
    {INN: "inn-3", KPP: "kpp-3"},
    {INN: "inn-4", KPP: "kpp-4"},
    {INN: "inn-5", KPP: "kpp-5"},
    {INN: "inn-7", KPP: "kpp-7"}
]
```

Comment: is it like all unique fields across all users or set of unique fields corresponding to particular user , nd this may help https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: The link above is not really what I want, but anyway, thank you! I added an example to clearify what I want :)

Comment: For a given `INN` / `KPP` combination, is `orgId` always the same?

Comment: Yes, orgId is always the same.

Comment: Then it should be as simple as (in the shell) `db.users.distinct('orgInfo')`

Comment: and can i then agregate just INN and KPP using mongoose, not running through the result with the cycle?

Comment: Anyway, great thanks to you! :)